# Adding View to TableLayout Takes Up Whole Screen

Tags: android, xamarin.android, tablelayout

I am simply trying to add a separator line under my header row in a table layout, but no matter what i set the width/height to in layoutparams, the view takes up the whole page.

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.counted);
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
TextView itemNumber = new TextView(this);
TextView itemDesc = new TextView(this);
TextView quantity = new TextView(this);

itemNumber.Text = "Item Number";
var inlo = new TableRow.LayoutParams(1);
inlo.SetMargins(10, 10, 30, 10);
itemNumber.LayoutParameters = inlo;

itemDesc.Text = "Item Description";
var idlo = new TableRow.LayoutParams(2);
idlo.SetMargins(10, 10, 30, 10);
itemDesc.LayoutParameters = inlo;

quantity.Text = "Quantity";
var qlo = new TableRow.LayoutParams(3);
qlo.SetMargins(10, 10, 30, 10);
quantity.LayoutParameters = qlo;

View v = new View(this);
v.LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent | 0);
v.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);

row.AddView(itemNumber);
row.AddView(itemDesc);
row.AddView(quantity);

tl.AddView(row);
tl.AddView(v);
```

v and its white background takes up the whole screen below row.  ????

Comment: What is the parent of your table? Can you paste your xml layout?

Comment: It's just an empty table layout.  <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/counted"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</TableLayout>

Comment: Try changing `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to `wrap_content` or place the table inside another layout.

Comment: Tried both.  Same result.  Added the tablelayout to a relativelayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just decided to use Strings to underline my column headers rather than trying to put a line under the first row.